# Logo in Navbar is not centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am running into an issue where the logo in the middle of my navbar is not centrally aligned. Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8zekvxqz/

```
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li > a > img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Holtwood One SC', serif;
}
```

You might need to resize the window of the jsfiddle to see what I am talking about as there are currently no media queries to reorganize the menu at the default jsfiddle window size.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I think it's centrally aligned. In smaller screens it seems oddly placed because the width of the image is fixed. You can give a max width to the image and let the logo become smaller in smaller screens. You can use class="img-responsive" if needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav ul{ 
  list-style-type: none; 
  text-align: center; 
}
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I believe retargeting the image is redundant:

```
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li > a > img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: I am glad and you're welcome! Please help me by voting my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you're wanting the image between **Menu** and **About us** then you need to remove `display:inline-block;` from `#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li`.

Comment: That centers it but it removes it from being inline with the nav selections. Thanks for your help, though.